# GO: Return map from SQL query

Tags: go

I am querying a mysql database in a GO function and want to return key value pairs in a map but can't quite figure out how to accomplish this. So far I have this function:

```
func GetData(callIds []string) map[string]Records {
    //db insert
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", mySql)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
    //db query
    var foo string
    err = db.QueryRow("select foo from bardata where callId = %v", 1).Scan(&foo)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(foo)

    return nil
```

I want to return a map with the key being `callId` and value being `foo` for each row returned from the query.

Comment: You have your function returning a `map[string]Records` but the thing you're fetching from the DB is a `string`, not a `Records`, whatever that is. What's supposed to happen there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to build up your query. As it is, you're not even using your function input. Since we have a variable number of arguments, we need to do a little work to construct the right number of placeholders:

```
query := `select callid, foo from bardata where callid in (` +
    strings.Repeat(`?,`, len(callIds) - 1) + `?)`
```

then, execute with the values passed in:

```
rows, err := db.Query(query, callIds...)
if err != nil {
    // handle it
}
defer rows.Close()
```

then collect the results:

```
ret := map[string]string{}
for rows.Next() {
    var callid, foo string
    err = rows.Scan(&callid, &foo)
    if err != nil {
        // handle it
    }
    ret[callid] = foo
}

return ret
```

Caveats:

1. This will cause a placeholder mismatch error if `callIds` is an empty slice. If that's possible, then you need to detect it and handle it separately (maybe by returning an error or an empty map — querying the DB shouldn't be necessary).
2. This returns a `map[string]string` where the values are whatever "foo" is. In your question you have the function returning a `map[string]Records` but there's no information about what a `Records` might be or how to fetch one.
3. You might want to handle `sql.ErrNoRows` differently from other errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/bobby96333/goSqlHelper"
)

func main(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
    conn,err :=goSqlHelper.MysqlOpen("user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname")
    checkErr(err)
    row,err := conn.QueryRow("select * from table where col1 = ? and  col2 = ?","123","abc")
    checkErr(err)
    if *row==nil {
        fmt.Println("no found row")
    }else{
        fmt.Printf("%+v",row)
    }
}

func checkErr(err error){
    if err!=nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

output:

&map[col1:abc col2:123]

Comment: Add some explanation to improve quality of your answer